# Why does the "initialvel" attribute remain equal to the "vel" attribute throughout the program?

Tags: python

I  am creating a physics engine in python pygame and have recently encountered a problem when trying to reset the velocities and positions of my particles (balls) when pressing r. I did a lot of tests and even asked chat GPT but all I found was that ball.initialvel = ball.vel after it is assigned, and does not hold its original value, changing every time ball.vel is changed, which should not happen as this part of the code is only called once. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import numpy as np
import pygame
from dataclasses import dataclass
import random
import string


# Molecular Dynamics
import pygame

# pygame setup
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1280, 720))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
dt = 0

#Constants and Initialisations
r = 40
M = 10
g = pygame.Vector2(0, 9.81)

#Classes and Functions

@dataclass 
class ball:
    
    #What properties is each ball going to have?
    rad: float = 40
    colour: str = "red"
    vel: pygame.Vector2 = None
    pos: pygame.Vector2 = None
    accel: pygame.Vector2 = None
    mass: float = 1
    initialvel: pygame.Vector2 = None **#initialised here**
    initialpos: pygame.Vector2 = None
    
    
    # Prevents bugs idfk
    def __post_init__(self):
        if self.pos is None:
            self.pos = pygame.Vector2(screen.get_width() / 2, screen.get_height() / 2)
        if self.vel is None:
            self.vel = pygame.Vector2(40,30)
        if self.accel is None:
            self.accel = g


    #Box collision algorithm reverses velocity when collides
    def BoxCollision(self):

        if self.pos.x - self.rad <= 50 or self.pos.x + self.rad >= 1230:
            self.vel.x = -self.vel.x
        
        if self.pos.y - self.rad <= 50 or self.pos.y + self.rad >= 670:
            self.vel.y = -self.vel.y
       
    #Frame by fram position update (verlet integration needed)
    def PosUpdate(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.colour, self.pos, self.rad)

        self.vel += self.accel * dt
        self.BoxCollision()
        self.pos += self.vel * dt
        

#Declarations of balls (objects)
ballR = ball()
ballB = ball(30,"blue" , pygame.Vector2(-35,40))
ballY = ball(30,"yellow" , pygame.Vector2(-55,100))

ballz = [ballR, ballB, ballY]

**#ball initial positions and velocities are set here, despite this only being run once, i.intialpos and i.initialvel remains stuck to i.pos and i.vel and does not keep its original value.**

for i in ballz: 
    i.initialpos = i.pos
    i.initialvel = i.vel

#Main Loop
while running:
    # poll loop for events
    # pygame.QUIT event means the user clicked X to close your window
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT or (event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
            running = False
            
# **Attempting to reset velocities and positions however they are equal at all times so this does nothing**
        #Restart function
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_r:
            for allballs in ballz:
                print("Before reset - Initial Velocity:", allballs.initialvel)
                print("Before reset - Velocity:", allballs.vel)
                allballs.pos = allballs.initialpos
                allballs.vel = allballs.initialvel  # Reset velocity to initial value
                print("After reset - Initial Velocity:", allballs.initialvel)
                print("After reset - Velocity:", allballs.vel)
            
        #Wait 1 minute for analysis
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_SPACE:
            pygame.time.wait(60000)

        #Create new ball function
        #if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN and event.key == pygame.K_b:

            #random.choice(string.ascii_letters) = ball(50, "green", pygame.Vector2(random.randrange(100), 9))

    # fill the screen with a color to wipe away anything from last frame
    screen.fill("black")
    
    # pygame.draw.rect(screen, colour, (x, y, width, height)
    box = pygame.draw.rect(screen, "blue", (50, 50, 1180, 620), width = 1)

    #position update
    ballR.PosUpdate()
    ballB.PosUpdate()
    ballY.PosUpdate()

    
    # flip() the display to put your work on screen
    pygame.display.flip()
    #print(ball_vel)
    
    # limits FPS to 60
    # dt is delta time in seconds(not really) since last frame, used for framerate-
    # independent physics.
    dt = clock.tick(144) / 100
    


    
pygame.quit()
```

Comment: because of this: ` i.initialvel = i.vel` . . . inside the for loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because for PyGame `Vector2`, `+=` is not the same as `=` followed by `+`. `+=` changes the value of the `Vector2` object, while `+` creates a new object. If you want to treat `Vector2`s like immutable values, the same as `int`s and `float`s, you should use `+`, not `+=`. Alternatively, you could use them as mutable but use `copy()` when you want a copy of their values.

When you write

```
initialvel = vel
vel += d
```

You are setting `initialvel` to be *the same object* as `vel`. That means any changes to this object will affect both, because they refer to the same object. Adding to it with `+=` changes both.

## immutable with `+`

If you write, instead:

```
initialvel = vel
vel = vel + d
```

That creates a new object to hold the result of `vel + d`, and sets `vel` to it. The original object that `initialvel` refers to is not changed.

## mutable with `+=` and `copy()`

If you write, instead:

```
initialvel = vel.copy()
vel += d
```

That creates a new object to save the old value of `vel` in `initialvel`. So afterwards, when the `vel` value is changed by adding to it, `initialvel`'s value is not.